# How to get correct regex for multiple \r\n?

Tags: python, regex

```
input text = 'DOCKET NO.  10-10 851\t)\tDATE\r\n\t)\r\n\t)\r\n\r\nOn appeal from the\r\nDepartment of Veterans Affairs Regional Office in Portland, Oregon\r\n'
```

I am looking to get offsets for texts split after regex pattern. The idea is to get text after splitting on any consecutive '\r\n' or '\n' eg: split on '\r\n\r\n' , '\r\n\r\n\r\n' , '\n\n' , '\n\n\n' and so on.

I have tried the following:

```
    s,e = 0,0
    newline_offsets = []
    for m in re.finditer(r'[\r\n | \n\n]{2,}', input_text,re.VERBOSE):    
        b1 = m.start()
        b2 = m.end()
        e= b1
        newline_offsets.append((s,e))
        s= b2
    len_text = len(input_text)
    if s != len_text:
        newline_offsets.append((s,len_text))
```

It does not seem to work.
My output is:

```
newline_offsets
Out[52]: [(0, 10), (12, 28), (30, 32), (34, 36), (40, 58), (60, 126)]
```

Expected output:

```
[(0, 36), (40, 128)]
```

Comment: By using `[` and `]` in your regexp, your matching each character individually, space and pipe included! Replace them with `(` and `)` respectively and remove the spaces (as they have meaning of matching a space in regexp, which you don't want)

Comment: split on `r'(\r?\n){2,}'` which isany two \n with optional \r in front of them.

Comment: Do you want just `re.split(r'[\r\n]+', text)`?

Answer (score 0):

The regex you should be using if you want to split on 2 or more of '\r\n' or '\n' should just be:

`(\r?\n){2,}`

And so:

```py
import re

input_text = 'DOCKET NO.  10-10 851\t)\tDATE\r\n\t)\r\n\t)\r\n\r\nOn appeal from the\r\nDepartment of Veterans Affairs Regional Office in Portland, Oregon\r\n'
s = 0
newline_offsets = []
for m in re.finditer(r'(\r?\n){2,}', input_text):
    b1 = m.start()
    b2 = m.end()
    e = b1
    newline_offsets.append((s, e))
    s = b2
len_text = len(input_text)
if s != len_text:
    newline_offsets.append((s, len_text))
print(newline_offsets)
```

Prints:

```None
[(0, 36), (40, 128)]
```